# How to call service when app install in device android?

Tags: android

If any one have idea when app install, I want to send user information with out user interaction.Please help me thanks in advance.which method will call when installing app in device.

Answer (score 1):

You would create a service, and in your Manifest.xml you would register a BroadcastReceiver for that service that listened for this filter: Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` broadcast do your task in receiver like following

**Register Receiver**

```
<receiver android:name=".ApplicationInstallationListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>  
         <data android:scheme="package"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**ApplicationInstallationListener.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ApplicationInstallationListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO send user information
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many samples on net . pls google on it.
 some url are

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/service/android-service-example/
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

to get user info

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html

```
.which method will call when installing app in device.
```

use "shared preference" . after install the app , change the boolean value is true.

handle that condition . initially it has be false at that time you call the service. after that you change the boolean value.